# Angulat, Http GET with wrong (split) queryParams

Tags: angular, query-string

I am trying to use queryParams so I would not create specific components in frontend (Angular) and backend( java spring boot).

I am making an e-commerce website look alike.
On my home page I have this.

```
  <a [routerLink]="['/ads']" [queryParams]="{category: 'multimedia'}">
```

in my ads component I made this,

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this.category = params['category'];
  console.log(this.category)
});
this.getAds();
}

getAds(): void {
console.log(this.category)

this.adService.getAds(this.category).subscribe(
  (ads) => {
    this.rowData = ads;
    this.isLoadingResults = false;
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    this.isLoadingResults = false;
  }
);
}
```

the console.logs get me the right parameter which is multimedia in this case but when the request is made with this code:

```
 getAds(param): Observable<Ad[]> {
return this.http.get<Ad[]>(apiUrl + "ads",{params: param}).pipe(
  tap(),
  catchError(this.handleError("getAds", []))
);
}
```

I see this:

```
http://localhost:9191/ads?0=m&1=u&2=l&3=t&4=i&5=m&6=e&7=d&8=i&9=a
```

And backend side the requestparam give me a null result.
What am I doing wrong?
PS: How can I do this also for multiple paramaters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use snapshot instead to get your queryPramas and initialize your category  in your constructor, i suggest this

```
category: string;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.category = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['category'];
}    

ngOnInit() {
 this.getAds();
}
 
...
```

Your service:

```
 getAds(param): Observable<Ad[]> {
  const params = new HttpParams()
  .set('category', param);
  return this.http.get<Ad[]>(apiUrl + "ads",{params}).pipe(
    tap(),
    catchError(this.handleError("getAds", []))
  );
 }
```

and if you want really to track queryParams values you can subscribe to queryParams as you did and move your getAds inside .subscribe giving it the category ad a parameter, that make your http call react to your query params changes:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this.category = params['category'];
  console.log(this.category)
  this.getAds(this.category); // move it inside and give it the category as parameter
 });
} 

getAds(category: string): void {
this.adService.getAds(category).subscribe(
  (ads) => {
    this.rowData = ads;
    this.isLoadingResults = false;
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    this.isLoadingResults = false;
  }
);
}
```

the best solution is case you need to listen to queryParams change is using **switchMap** rxjs operator, that will cancel the previous http calls in case or a new query param value, if the user clicks more than one link in a short span of time then  only latest clicked link will be considered

Comment: Still the same issue, `http://localhost:4200/ads?category=multimedia` is the  link frontend and for the request this is what appears `http://localhost:9191/ads?0=m&1=u&2=l&3=t&4=i&5=m&6=e&7=d&8=i&9=a` which is very weird

Comment: in your service make this changes  getAds(param): Observable<Ad[]> {
  const params = new HttpParams()
  .set('category', param);
  return this.http.get<Ad[]>(apiUrl + "ads",{params}).pipe(
    tap(),
    catchError(this.handleError("getAds", []))
  );
 }

Comment: this actually works, but there is still the question about multiple parameters, how can I do that?
for example: ` <a [routerLink]="['/ads']" [queryParams]="{category: 'shoes' ,category: 'pants'}">` , with this methode, I only get the secon parameter.

Comment: how comes params with the same name

Comment: it is actually the same parameter but with diifrent values

Comment: in case you send an object  getAds(object) {  this.http.get<Ad[]>(apiUrl + "ads",{params: object})}

Comment: the problem is the object I get takes this form ` { undefined: "shoes", category: "pants" }
 `

Comment: in that case you have to that: getAds(param1:string, param2:string): Observable<Ad[]> { const params = new HttpParams() .set('category', param1).set(('category', param2); return this.http.get<Ad[]>(apiUrl + "ads",{params}).pipe( tap(), catchError(this.handleError("getAds", [])) );

Answer (score 0):

When we make a router URL with a parameter we have some router like this

```
const routes: Routes =[{ path: 'example/:category', component: examolComponents}];
```

after that, we can set from a tag like this

```
<a [routerLink]="['/example', 'multimedia']">
```

after that we need calling category from component and take that like this

```
category: string;
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
       route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
         this.category = params['params'].category
       });
   }
```